# Onclick method will not get called

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

I am developing an android application.I am new to android.The Onclick method is not being fired.I have been trying to figure it out for hours. I have checked the button ID and the code several times. I have posted my code below. Please help.

```
package com.android.disasterAlertApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Registration extends Activity{
Button sqlRegister;
EditText  sqlFirstName,sqlLastName,sqlEmail,sqlMobileNumber,sqlCurrentLocation,sqlUsername,sqlPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.registration);
    sqlFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFname);
    sqlLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLname);

    sqlRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
    sqlRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "fire", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

------------------------XML File--------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="536dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First Name"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etFname"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:ems="10"

    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Last Name"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etLname"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Email"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etEmail"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />


/////This is the Register Button/////
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bRegister"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="92dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Register"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

 </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you also post the registration xml file?

Comment: Your code looks fine.. Post your layout file...

Comment: your code perfect  try to print log and also clean project

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited it. I get no errors. I have tried cleaning it too.

Comment: try a couple of adb log statements like "in Registration.CreateView()" and "in SQLRegister.onClick()" and watch your adb log. Also, is this all your code? You don't have any extra overridden methods in the activity?

Comment: Please let us know if there is any thing more in code which is not mentioned above. as http://stackoverflow.com/a/10938416/804447

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the above code at may in a test `project and it is working fine` ....please see the image attached

[image]

Please let us know if there is any thing more in code which is not mentioned above.

Comment: Wow its actually working.Apart from the Registration Class i have other  Classes as well.

Comment: And other XML Files. Can those be the cause of the problem?

Comment: It works fine now. I was running a splash screen before it, I took it off now it works. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it up a different way by adding the following to your button xml

```
android:onClick="onClickHandler"
```

And then in your activity, define this method:

```
public void onClickHandler(View target) {
   switch (target.getId()) {
      case R.id.bRegister:
         //doSomething
     break;
   }
}
```